# Protection against git removal of untracked .gitignored files in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, sqlite, development-environment

I managed to delete to following files with git clean in my rails app:

```
Removing .DS_Store
Removing .bundle/
Removing config/application.yml
Removing db/development.sqlite3
Removing log/development.log
Removing public/system/profiles/avatars/000/000/011/
Removing public/system/profiles/avatars/000/000/012/
Removing tmp/
```

Are there any chances of getting back these files somehow or being able to copy from somewhere else? (Git deletes files permanently, so trash is empty. I also tried w/ disk drill but id didn't work out either.)

How can I protect my gitignored files properly to avoid these kinda situations in the future? Should I copy them sometimes or there are other programs to handle this?
Do I have to recreate my rails app or somebody knows a better option?

Comment: unless you wiped them from github they should be in you commit history. You can recreate the files in the appropriate places and copy/paste the code from your github repo

Comment: With git clean -x -d -f I deleted the untracked files. These files were untracked because were contained within the .gitignore file, so as far as I know I 've never pushed them to github.

Comment: You probably didn't want to say `-x` as that explicitly deletes ignored files ... exactly what you didn't want.  But that's for the future.  Nothing is likely to fix the past, I'm sorry to say.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try to find these files in previous commits.

Next time remove using command `git rm --cached file_name`

Comment: With git clean -x -d -f I deleted the untracked files. These files were untracked because were contained within the .gitignore file, so as far as I know I 've never pushed them to github.

Comment: So, I think it will be difficult to restore them.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pull it off. I ran bundle install (creates the files within .bundle) and reinstalled sqlite and figaro. After that I ran rake db:migrate which created the development.sqlite3 file. I lost the development data, but it is not a huge problem at all. For figaro I had to retype the keys and passwords (Sendgrid, Stripe, etc.) into the new application.yml file. Temporary and log files don't seem to be important. Thanks for the answers. This $git clean is pretty dangerous, watch out!